# Receiving type error when comparing two variables python 3

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

Python 3 code

```
import time

list = [1,2,3,4,2323449,1,525]

def Search(arr):
    # sorting
    i = 0
    print(f"Given list: {list}")
    print("Sorting...")
    time.sleep(1.75)
    for i in range(len(list)): 
        if i + 1 >= len(list):
            break
        elif  list[i + 1] < list[i]: 
            list.sort()
            print("List has been sorted ")
            print(f"Sorted list: {list}")
    #---------------------------------------
    # searching
    inputCheck = True
    while inputCheck:
        n = input("Enter a number to find in the list: ")
        try:
            int(n)
            inputCheck = False                                                                                                                                                                                            
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print("Please enter a number")
            time.sleep(0.6)



    print("Searching...")

    l = 0
    h = len(list) - 1 

    while l <= h:
        mid = (l + h) // 2

        if list[mid] == n:
            pos = mid
            print(f"Found at index {pos}")
            break
        else:
            print(n)
            if list[mid] < n:
                l = mid
            else:
                h = mid
            
Search(list)
```

I am trying to make a binary search program where the user enters the number that needs to be found in the list, however when this code is executed I receive this error:

```
if list[mid] < n:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: `input("Enter...)` gives you a string. Later on you compare it with a number. You can cast the input line to an int: `n = int(input("Enter a number to find in the list: "))`

Comment: alternatively in your "try" block...  You need to catch the conversion of n into an int by doing:  `n = int(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in your implementation

1. If input is valid number than searching block will execute so, in try block you have to store the value of n i.e, `n=int(n)`.
2. If `n` does not exist in your list than `l=mid` and `h=mid` will run while loop infinitely, as you have already check for index `mid` so set `l=mid+1` and `h=mid-1`, in while loop of binary search.

   **Please see below code with comments where you need changes**

```
import time

list = [1,2,3,4,2323449,1,525]

def Search(arr):
    # sorting
    i = 0
    print(f"Given list: {list}")
    print("Sorting...")
    time.sleep(1.75)
    for i in range(len(list)): 
        if i + 1 >= len(list):
            break
        elif  list[i + 1] < list[i]: 
            list.sort()
            print("List has been sorted ")
            print(f"Sorted list: {list}")
    #---------------------------------------
    # searching
    inputCheck = True
    while inputCheck:
        n = input("Enter a number to find in the list: ")  
        try:
            n=int(n)                        # if input is valid value then seaching will be done so store that number 
            inputCheck = False                                                                                                                                                                                            
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print("Please enter a number")
            time.sleep(0.6)


    print("Searching...")

    l = 0
    h = len(list) - 1 

    while l <= h:
        mid = (l + h) // 2

        if list[mid] == n:
            pos = mid
            print(f"Found at index {pos}")
            break
        else:
            print(n)
            if list[mid] < n:
                l = mid+1           # as index mid has already checked so set l=mid+1
            else:
                h = mid-1           # mid has already checked so set h=mid-1
            
Search(list)
```